# Introductory reference for Hardy spaces on the disk

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, hardy-spaces

I'm looking for a good introductory reference for $H^p$ spaces on the unit disk. I already have a good background in real/complex analysis and functional analysis. I currently have the text *Funtion Classes on the Unit Disk* by Pavlović, but I'd like a reference with more complete proofs if possible. My goal is to study the boundary behavior of $H^p$ functions.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: This topic should be covered in some more advanced complex analysis textbooks, for example in John Conway and Barry Simon's second volumes.

Comment: Duren's monograph on the subject is the best introduction I know; there are two other very good monographs by Mashreghi and Koosis respectively, but Duren is the best introduction imho